# Getting blurred image after extracting AOI through shapefile from USGS data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, clip, extract-by-mask, usgs

I intended to generate DEM of required location using ArcGIS Pro. Using USGS Earth Explorer, I downloaded the SRTM DEM as a *.tiff* file for a huge block of area which consists my desired area in it.
Now I want to extract my area of interest from the obtained DEM file.
I used "Clip Raster" [Data Management tool] feature in ArcGIS Pro to clip the DEM into a perfect shape for my desired location.
Now this extracted Raster clip is very blurry.
How do I resolve this?

[image: ORIGINAL IMAGE]

This is the original DEM file in *.tiff* format that I downloaded from USGS Earth Explorer indicating a huge block of area.

[image: DETAILS OF SRTM DEM FILE DOWNLOADED FROM USGS-1]

[image: DETAILS OF SRTM DEM FILE DOWNLOADED FROM USGS-2]

The above pictures denotes the details of the original dem image

[image]

The above image depicts the clipped images from the dem file.
This image is too blurred to visualize in ArcGIS Pro.

[image: DETAILS OF CLIPPED DEM FILE -1]

[image: DETAILS OF CLIPPED DEM FILE -2]

The above images show the details of the clipped image.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: You left out the command you used to clip the data. You probably resampled it accidently. It would help if the clip window was presented on the original layer. Look in the Geoprocessing log for the clip command, Copy as Python snippet, and paste in the Question.

Comment: More info please... What is the source (SRTM, GTOPO, something else) and resolution (pixel size) of the original DEM? What is the resolution of the clipped DEM? What is the extent of your AOI?

Comment: As noted, it would be good to see the Geoprocessing call.  You could right-click and export to a python snippet so we could see all of the values used in the respective parameters.  My assumption is the Cell Size environment needs to be set to match the input cell size.  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/environment-settings/cell-size.htm

Comment: You should always specify a `.tif` suffix on the output raster, so you get a GeoTIFF output.  The clip seems to be quite small (35x58 pixels), so there isn't much that Pro can do.

Comment: The resolution of the clipped DEM is exactly the same as the original (1 arc second ~= 30m). Clipping didn't make it blurry, it's just not a high enough resolution for you and the small AOI.  You probably need to find some high res. data, such as a Lidar derived DEM.